# Return type mismatch in function declared to return record

Tags: sql, postgresql, next.js, supabase

I am trying to create a function that is being used to perform a full text search. I don't think I'm understanding how to return things correctly. I need the full record found from the original table returned to me, as I will use all rows when these returned records are found. This will be used on a front end by Next.js utilizing supabase as the back end.

I got these to work before but it really appears it's just not working now.

My table rows go exactly according to the return statement listed in this declaration, that is, my rows in the origin table to be searched are id, title ,author, image, postdate, and postcontent.

Then in the to_tsvector are the columns i'm proving to match content on based in the input keyword. I have a working version of this already, but have lost the origin query that allowed me to create this function in the first place.

I am getting the error: `return type mismatch in function declared to return record`

```
create or replace function search_blog_ts_fixed(keyword text)
returns table(id int, title text, author text, image text, postdate date, postcontent text)
as
$$
SELECT *
from posts
WHERE to_tsvector(title || ' ' || author || ' ' || postdate || ' ' || postcontent) @@ to_tsquery(keyword)
$$
language sql
```

Comment: I'm going to say `SELECT * ...` does not expand to exactly the same columns/types as that declared in `table()`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it's so odd, because I flipped the position of author and title, and then flipped the positin of image and postdate. In Supabase, where all of this is stored, I don't see the exact structure of the table, so I'm not sure if ordering is what's causing the issue.

Comment: Why do you use a * in the first place? Any change in the table "post" will now cause a failure in this function.

Comment: You can't use [Tables](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/tables)? Working on unknown structure is a recipe for mistakes.  In any case you can do `select * from posts` outside the function to see the columns and order. To inspect data types see [pg_typeof](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-info.html); `select pg_typeof(<some_field>)` will return the data type.

Comment: Another option to see the database schema(tables, etc) is to install `psql` or another client on your end and use that to connect to the `Supabase` server.